# get selectItem on change event

Tags: javascript, html, web-frameworks, sencha-touch-2

Given the following code in Sencha Touch (pr3), I allways get "all" in the alert.

```js
{
    xtype:'selectfield',
    options: [
        {text: 'AllInboxes(5)', name:'all',value: 'all'},
        {text: 'Correspondence(2)',name:'cores', value: 'correspondence'},
        {text: 'ERP(2)', name:'erp',value: 'erp'},
        {text: 'Media(1)', name:'med', value: 'media'}
    ],
    listeners: {
        change: function(value){
            alert(value.originalValue);
            //Pass value parameter to the 2nd select field's store
        }
    },
}
```

Could some one please let me know what is the issue ?

Below code works:

```
 change: function(field, value) {
                if (value instanceof Ext.data.Model) {
                    value = value.get(field.getValueField());
                }
                console.log(value);
                //Pass value parameter to the 2nd select field's store
            }
```

Comment: So, you answered it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

See the [documentation for the change listener](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.field.Select-event-change).

It take three parameters

- field
- new value
- old value

So try to use it this way :

```
change: function(field, newValue, oldValue){
  alert(newValue);
}
```

Hope this helps